# Convert rows to columns in Python (jupyter)

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a excel in below format:

[How the data is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcP1q.jpg)

I want to convert the rows into columns as below:

[How the data should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REAun.jpg)

How can I do this transformation using Python? Thank you!

Comment: Hi! Please try to post your data as code instead of images: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('your_excel_file.xlsx')
df = df.pivot(index='Data', columns='Station', values='Average')
```

Answer (score 0):

from what i understand this would be the solution you need.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Station': ["Parque Dom Pedro II","Parque Dom Pedro II",
                    "Parque Dom Pedro II","Parque Dom Pedro II","Parque Dom Pedro II","Parque Dom Pedro II"],
                    'Pollutant':['MP2.5','MP2.5','MP2.5','MP2.5','MP2.5','MP2.5'],
                   'Data': ['05/07/2016 00:00','05/07/2016 01:00',
                   '05/07/2016 02:00','05/07/2016 03:00','05/07/2016 04:00','05/07/2016 04:00'],
                   'Average':['75,21','71,04','58,47','48,28','38,39','29,64']})


row = df['Average'].values.tolist()
col = df['Station'].values.tolist()

data = {'Data': df['Data'].values.tolist(), "Parque Dom Pedro II": []}
for x in range(0, len(col)):
    if (df['Station'][x] == "Parque Dom Pedro II"):
        data["Parque Dom Pedro II"].append(row[x])


nw_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print("FIRST DATAFRAME:\n" + str(df) + "\n\nSECOND DATAFRAME:\n" + str(nw_df))
```

If your table has more than one station, there is this other way to do it

```
import pandas as pd
def condition(df, len_col, col):
    data = []
    for x in range(0, len_col):
        if (df['Station'][x] == col):
            data.append(row[x]) 
        else:
            data.append('') 
    return data

df = pd.DataFrame({'Station': ["Parque Dom Pedro II","Parque Dom Pedro II",
                    "Parque Dom Pedro II","Parque Dom Pedro II","Parque Dom Pedro II","Another Station",
                    "Another Station","Another Station","Another Station","Another Station"],
                    'Pollutant':['MP2.5','MP2.5','MP2.5','MP2.5','MP2.5','MP2.5','MP2.5','MP2.5','MP2.5','MP2.5'],
                   'Data': ['05/07/2016 00:00','05/07/2016 01:00',
                   '05/07/2016 02:00','05/07/2016 03:00','05/07/2016 04:00','05/07/2016 05:00',
                   '05/07/2016 06:00','05/07/2016 06:30','05/07/2016 07:00','05/07/2016 08:00'],
                   'Average':['75,21','71,04','58,47','48,28','38,39','29,64','29,64','29,64','29,64','29,64']})


row = df['Average'].values.tolist()
col = df['Station'].values.tolist()

data = {'Data': df['Data'].values.tolist(), "Parque Dom Pedro II": []}

temp_col = col[0]
data[temp_col] = condition(df, len(col), temp_col)
for x in range(0, len(col)):
    if (temp_col != col[x]):
        temp_col = col[x]
        data[temp_col] = condition(df, len(col), temp_col)


nw_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print("FIRST DATAFRAME:\n" + str(df) + "\n\nSECOND DATAFRAME:\n" + str(nw_df))
```